# DataStructure + Algorithm for filesystem-like tree with links

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, filesystems, computer-science, hierarchy

I'm trying to model some data that is like a filesystem, but I have to use a database.

**Data set:**

Dot-delimited text strings like a.b1.c1.d.e, a.b2.c2, etc.

All strings conform to conventions that there is a root node, 'root', presumed to be at the start of all the strings, which makes it a hierarchical data structure.

Each node has a limited set of sub-nodes as children.

This is all easy enough to implement, just put the nodes in a table with name and a list of children to make searching faster than O(n).

**Complication**

The problem comes with the fact that sometimes we need to have cross-links, just like symbolic links in a filesystem.  So, let's say we have:

- root.a              -> children: b
- root.a.b            -> children: c
- root.a.b.c          -> children: d
- root.a.b.c.d        -> children: None
- root.p              -> children: q
- root.p.q           --> link to a.b, so children: c

**Question 1:**

What on God's green Earth is the 'computer science'-name for this kind of tree structure?  I would call this an acyclic digraph, but that's kind of general as a name, I'm thinking there has to be better name for this.  Trees are defined not to have multiple inheritance, so that's out.

I want to know the name because I'm hoping someone has a set of algorithms that implement this structure and thus will save me having to define these classes at great personal hassle.

**Question 2:**

If I'm looking to verify p.q.c.d, it seems I have to:

- look for p.q.c.d and if it exists, return it.
- retrieve p.q.c, p.q, and p, find that p.q is a link to a.b
- construct a.b.c.d and test that, if so return it.
- otherwise fail

**Question 3:**

When I'm looking through this thing using GLOBS (* / ? / [1234] regex-like queries) the search gets more complex.

**Background**

1. I'd like to not reinvent the wheel here.  The actual use case is a database to store data for Graphite monitoring data, which has a back-end datastore of a filesystem.  I need (for many reasons) to put data into a database, and thus have to create a model of it.
2. Is there a reference implementation of something similar?
3. Thanks for your consideration, and apologies if my meager brain capacity makes this out to be a harder problem than it is.
4. I happen to be working in Python, but I can translate from any other convenient language or parallel dimensional construct as long as it doesn't involve too much witchcraft or hyperbolic swearing of fealty to God-like netherworldish beings.

Comment: The best name I can come up with would be "directed acyclic graph" (like feedforward neural networks)

Comment: For Q1: it's an acyclic digraph

Comment: It's only a DAG if you forbid cycles. So you can't go a.b.c => a (the acyclic part).  In general these are directed graphs, the acyclic part just makes certain things easier.  What's the question for question2? Is it "Is this all I need to do?" because that depends on your business logic, i.e. forbidding cycles. I feel that you could simplify it by using recursion. resolve(x) -> blah blah, if link return resolve(link). Also, what's the question for question 3?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this representation called the "path enumeration model" or the "Dewey Decimal" system. (The underlying logical structure is an acyclic digraph with a single root as you have noted.)